# Simple Discord Python Bot Err0r

Tags: python

apparently I am creating a simple discord reply bot and I have an error with my code. Even if I say the correct word with $ in chat, it is still using and replying to me with the else statement. I do not have this problem on the replit, but I do on my home PC, what could be the problem?

```py
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send("Hello World!")
  else:
    await message.channel.send("Hello World! BUT ERROR")

@client.event
async def on_connect():
  print("Bot Connected")
    
client.run(TOKEN)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o85jU.png)

Comment: Question is too vague and unclear. What exactly is your issue? Please describe it in detail.

Comment: So, i have a python bot that is supposed to reply "Hello World!" whenever I say '$hello'. The code is right since I have copied it from the video. This code works perfectly fine if I run it from the website Repl.it, but if I run this code from my Computer (e.g. Console (sublime text) The bot is not properly working. He is always replying with "Hello World! BUT ERROR" even if I type the correct '$hello'

Comment: Alright, I've written an answer. Try the solution and see if it can solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. I suggest that you use the following code instead.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.lower() == '$hello':
    await message.channel.send("Hello World!")
  else:
    await message.channel.send("Hello World! BUT ERROR")
```

What I have changed here is using the string matching instead of `startswith()` function.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for trying but it is still the same issue. Error reply.

Comment: I’m haven’t code the discord bot frequently, but I remember that, if I remember it correctly, the discord API may have some problem with else statement. Thus, you may consider using other statement  such as elif instead. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Your bot does not have the **Message Content Intents**, so it will not be able to read messages sent by users.

In discord.py 2.0, a bot must have the Message intent in order to read messages' content.

To enable Message Intents for your bot, follow these steps:

1. Go to [Discord's developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and click on your application's name.
2. Click on "Bot" in the sidebar.
3. Scroll down until you see `"Privileged Gateway Intents"`.
4. You should see the option named `"Message Content Intent"`. Enable it.

[image: The option for Message Content Intent]

**The next step:**
At the start of your bot code, you should have a line of code that creates a `Client` or `Bot` object, for example:
`client = discord.Client()` or `bot = discord.Bot(...)`

First, you should define a variable `intents`:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()  # define intents
```

**Now, add the parameter `intents` to the object, like this:**

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

or:

```py
bot = discord.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

And you are all set!

Hope this helped.